# Get terms of a taxonomy using useSelect

Tags: javascript, hooks, block-editor, rest-api

I'm developing a Gutenberg block and I need to show a dropdown with all the terms of a custom taxonomy in it. I'm using the `useSelect` hook for retrieving this data, but it's not working because it gets stuck showing the `Loading...` message and there are no errors in the console. I registered the taxonomy with the `show_in_rest` arg set to true.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const { Placeholder, SelectControl } = wp.components;
const { useSelect } = wp.data;

const blockAttributes = {
    slug: {
        type: 'string',
        default: '',
    },
};

export const name = 'my-plugin/my-terms-block';

export const settings = {
    title: 'My Terms Block' ),
    attributes: blockAttributes,

    edit: ( props => {
        const { attributes, className } = props;

        const terms = useSelect( ( select ) =>
            select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'my_taxonomy', { per_page: -1, orderby: 'name', order: 'asc', _fields: 'name,slug' } )
        );
        
        const setSlug = value => {
            props.setAttributes( { slug: value } );
        };

        if ( ! terms ) {
            return 'Loading...';
        }

        if ( terms.length === 0 ) {
            return 'No terms found' );
        }

        var options = [];
        options.push( {
            label: 'Select a term...',
            value: ''
        } );

        for ( var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++ ) {
            options.push( {
                label: terms[i].name,
                value: terms[i].slug
            } );
        }

        return (
            <Placeholder
                key='my-terms-block'
                label={ 'Terms Block' }
                className={ className }>
                    <SelectControl
                        label={ 'Select a term:' }
                        value={ attributes.slug }
                        options={ options }
                        onChange={ setSlug }
                    />
            </Placeholder>
        );

    } ),

};

registerBlockType( name, settings );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `_fields` argument, then it needs to include `id`. Otherwise, `getEntityRecords()` will always return a `null`, even if the REST API request succeeded.

So to fix the issue in question, you just need to add `id` to your args, i.e. `_fields: 'id,name,slug'`.

You should also know that `per_page` is limited to `100`, so even if you set it to a greater number or even `-1` (which means all), the value is always set to max 100.